# Are these proofs all right? (Automorphism group of a string).

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, formal-languages

[Background.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1210759/finite-groups-acting-on-strings)  Let $G$ be the automorphism group of a string $s$, ie. $G = \langle (i,j) : i \lt j, s[i] = s[j]\rangle$.  Then $G$ is a normal subgroup of $S_{|s|}$ the symmetry group on $|s|$ symbols.

Proof. $G \approx S_{k_1} \times \cdots \times S_{k_n} = H_1 \cdot H_2 \cdots H_n$ where $H_i = 1 \times \dots \times 1\times S_{k_i} \times 1 \times \dots \times 1$ each of which is isomorphic to $S_{k_i}$.  Each such copy is normal as $S_{k_i}$ is the symmetric group on $k_i$ symbols and contains every transposition on $k_i$ symbols.  In other words use that to prove $\tau S_{k_i} = S_{k_i}\tau, \ \ \forall $ transpositions $\tau \in S_{|s|}$.

<strike>Also, there is a homomorphism from $S_{|s|}$ onto $G$ given my multiplying all the projections together.</strike>

Are these correct proofs?

Comment: No, $\tau S_{k_i}\neq S_{k_i}\tau$. That step is wrong - it is only true for $\tau\in G$. Pick $\tau=(i,j)$ where $s[i]\neq s[j]$.

Comment: Let $s="aab"$, let $\tau=(1,3)$. $S_{i_1}=\{e,(1,2)\}$ and $\tau S_{i_1}\neq S_{i_1}\tau$.

Comment: (Your statement is, in fact, not true.)

Comment: As for the second part, what projections? You have a prijection from $G$ to $S_{k_i}$ but not from $S_{|s|}$ to $S_{k_i}$.

Comment: @ThomasAndrews if $s[i] \neq s[j]$ and $\{i,j\} \cap \{u, v\} = \varnothing$, then $(i,j)$ clearly commutes with $(u,v)$.  And if $(u,v) = (i,j)$ they clearly commute.  And if they share an index, then $((u,v) (u,j))(u,v) = (v,j)(u,v) = (u,j)$.  So where is the problem?

Comment: So $G=\{e,(1,2)\}$ is the automorphism subgroup of "AAB." Is that really a normal subgroup of $S_3$?